# How to ensure the difference of two elements of a number field are inside its ring of integers.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be a number field with $\omega_1,\omega_2\in K$ such that the following principal fractional ideals factor, in lowest terms, as
$(\omega_1)=\frac{\mathfrak{b}_1}{\mathfrak{a}}$ and $(\omega_2)=\frac{\mathfrak{b}_2}{\mathfrak{a}}$ for ideals $\mathfrak{b}_1, \mathfrak{b}_2, \mathfrak{a}$. Is it possible to find $\chi\in\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $\chi\omega_1-\omega_2\in\mathcal{O}_K$?

Comment: I don’t want to go in and correct the grammar of your Subject, but the question should be whether the difference **is** inside the ring… Remember, mathematics has to do with precision, and if you aren’t precise about what you’re asking, you’re being unmathematical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, let $\mathfrak{c}$ be an integral ideal  such that $\mathfrak{c} \mathfrak{a}=(\gamma)$ is principal. Then $(\gamma \, \omega_1)=\mathfrak{c}  \mathfrak{b}_1 $ and $(\gamma \, \omega_2)=\mathfrak{c}  \mathfrak{b}_2 $ and since $\mathfrak{a}$ is prime to $\mathfrak{b}_1 $ we have $(\gamma \, \omega_1)+(\gamma)=\mathfrak{c}$, also $\gamma \, \omega_2 \in \mathfrak{c}$, thus exists $\chi$ and $\lambda$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that  $\gamma \, \omega_2=\chi(\gamma \, \omega_1)+\lambda \gamma $, now cancel $\gamma$ and we're done.